# roslib.load_manifest error - Python

Tags: python, kinect, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to convert the points in PointCloud2 Messages to a numpy array, now, my main problem is whenever I try to use this line:

`import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('python_msg_conversions')`

I'm importing the roslib etc.. I get the following error:

```
$ python talker.py 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "talker.py", line 1, in <module>
    import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('python_msg_conversions')
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 62, in load_manifest
    sys.path = _generate_python_path(package_name, _rospack) + sys.path
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 93, in _generate_python_path
    m = rospack.get_manifest(pkg)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 159, in get_manifest
    return self._load_manifest(name)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 198, in _load_manifest
    retval = self._manifests[name] = parse_manifest_file(self.get_path(name), self._manifest_name)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 190, in get_path
    raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)
rospkg.common.ResourceNotFound: python_msg_conversions
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/O/src
ROS path [2]=/home/catkin_ws/src
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/hydro/share
ROS path [4]=/opt/ros/hydro/stacks
```

I have no idea as to why I'm getting this error either.

I hope someone can help me

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/107261/roslib.load_manifest-error---python/) by [Phorce](https://answers.ros.org/users/9496/phorce/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2013-12-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
rospkg.common.ResourceNotFound: python_msg_conversions
```

It looks like the `python_msg_conversions` package isn't on the search path. Do you have it installed?

---

Edit: just now noticed you're on Hydro. Is this a catkin package? The rospy tutorials (see [Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber) for instance) show that catkin packages should no longer use `roslib.load_manifest(..)`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2013-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-12-09**:
Alternatively, [this link](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/what#Python_Modules_.28Libraries.29) explain the change well too.